# Getting information from Django custom signal receiver

Tags: django, django-signals

This is my second question today actually but what I want to know...Is it possible to retrieve information from a signal handler.

I have a list of items, call it list and each item is in AppA. Each item has a couple of characteristics which are saved in a different app, AppB.

So, I figured that I could maybe create a dictionary, dict and iterate over the items in list. In each iteration, I was hoping to send a signal to AppB and retrieve the information, i.e. have something like

```
def blob(request):
    dict = {}
    for item in list:
        signal.send(sender=None, id=item.id)
        dict[item] = (char1, char2)
    ...some html request
```

My signal handler looks something like this:

```
def handler(sender, id, **kwargs):
    model2 = Model2.objects.get(id=id)
    a = model2.char1
    b = model2.char2
    return (a, b)
```

Then I was hoping to be able to just produce a list of the items and their characteristics in the webpage...THe problem is that obviously the signal sender has to send the signal, and get the information back which I want....is that even possible :S?

Currently, I get an error saying "global name 'char1' is not defined....and I have imported the handlers and signals into the view.py where blob resides....so is my problem just unsolvable? / Should it clearly be solved in another way? Or have I almost certainly made a stupid error with importing stuff?

Comment: You want to send some data via the signal and then get the data back from the signal when it's done?

Comment: Yes, and hopefully use said data in the html request at the end of blob.

Comment: You want to start looking into Message Queues for this. Celery being THE client for Django.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I mean that looks reasonably tricky....felt like it should be really simple? How about if I pass a and b, with default values in the signal sender. Then the handler updates them?...

Comment: I mean the current result is that I get a Name Error, "global name 'blah' is not defined" when I try to use 'blah' in my blob function

Comment: This is an attempt to abuse the signal system. If you want a return value, use a method or function call. The intent of a signal is that it is sent without concern for how it gets used such that one or more 'observers' can make use of the signal to do their own thing.

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't actually so tricky. Thought I should perhaps post how it was solved. In my views, I actually wrote

```
    response_list=signal.send(sender=None, list=list_of_items)
```

I then iterated over my response_list, adding the items to a fresh list like so:

```
    snippets = []
    for response in response_list:
    logger.error(response)
    snippets.append(response[1])
```

And could then call the responses in snippets like a dictionary in my template. When I asked the question, I didn't appreciate that I could equate something with the signal sending...